# Horizontal List View with bounce effect

Tags: android, horizontallist

Are there other ways to implement a Horizontal ListView in Android with bouncing/ recoil effect after it reaches the end of the list? 
I used this [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). 
Then since i'm also implementing a bouncing effect in my ListView (vertical)..I used this:

```
 public class BounceListView extends ListView
 {
     private static final int MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE = 100;

     private Context mContext;
    private int mMaxYOverscrollDistance;

    public BounceListView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceListView();
    }

    public BounceListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceListView();
    }

    public BounceListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceListView();
    }

    private void initBounceListView()
    {
        //get the density of the screen and do some maths with it on the max overscroll distance
        //variable so that you get similar behaviors no matter what the screen size

        final DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            final float density = metrics.density;

        mMaxYOverscrollDistance = (int) (density * MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) 
    { 
        //This is where the magic happens, we have replaced the incoming maxOverScrollY with our own custom variable mMaxYOverscrollDistance; 
        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, mMaxYOverscrollDistance, isTouchEvent);  
    }

 }
```

So, what i thought was since this class was used to implement a recoil/bounce effect, why not modify this for my HorizontalListView..so i created a class similar to this but extended it to HorizontalListView then change instead of `y` to `x`. But it didn't work. One thing also, `overScrollBy` is not defined in AdapterView (since HorizontalListVIew extends to this.)
Are there ways to implement a horizontal list with bounce? or are there open source libraries that could be of help?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe there have been a few legal issues with this one!  http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57577405-37/uspto-reaffirms-invalidation-of-apple-patent-in-samsung-suit/

Comment: so you're saying that i should not implement this one?

Comment: I'm just saying there's a reason you don't see it in other places.

Comment: did you implement bounce ??? can you share related link??

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple library [rotate-layout](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout) that allows to rotate [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) to the horizontal orientation (-90 degrees). All touch events works OK. Also you have to turn every item to +90 degrees, but it is also simple. Having ListView in the horizontal orientation you can avoid using [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView).